# How can I conclude $E_i(N_i) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n \cdot P_i(N_i=n) = \infty$ when $j$ is a recurrent state in Markov chain $X$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a Markov chain and let $N_j$ denote the number of times $X$ visits state $j$ after time $n=0$.

Suppose $j$ is recurrent, then I know $P_i(N_i = \infty) = P_i(X \ \text{visits state j infinitely often})= 1$.

How can I then conclude $$E_i(N_i) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} n \cdot P_i(N_i=n) = \infty$$

where $E_i$ denote the mean under $P_i$ ?

As I see it $\{ N_i = n\} \subsetneq \{ N_i = n+1\}$ and I cannot set $n = \infty$ in the sum :S.

Answer (score 1):

Soooo... you are asking why, if $X$ is a random variable such that $P(X=+\infty)=1$, then $E(X)=+\infty$, right?

Comment: Yes, I could describe the case like that I guess. But $\infty$ is not a real value ? Can $\infty$ be in the range of $X$ viewed formally as a function ?

Comment: In the sum above we never get the term $P(X = \infty)$ ??

Comment: "Can ∞ be in the range of X viewed formally as a function ?" It seems it does, very much, if, as in your post, one assumes that $P(X=+\infty)=1$.

Comment: "In the sum above we never get the term P(X=∞)" Right, which is the reason why it is a bad idea to use a formula made for almost surely finite random variables, to compute the expectation of a random variable which is not almost surely finite.

Comment: But then in the sum of $E_i(N_i)$, I never get the term $P_i(N_i=\infty)$ since we are iterating over all natural numbers ?  But since $P_i(N_i=\infty) = 1$ we must have $P_i(N_i\neq\infty)= 0$ ? So the sum is equal to $0$ ?

Comment: I guess the book I'm reading has made a mistake then.

Comment: I guess you are not even reading my comments.

Comment: I am reading your comments, but sometimes a cross-post happens.

Comment: Right, so now that the crossposting is over, does this solve your problem?

Comment: You say the formula is used incorrectly in the context. So the author of these notes made a mistake ?

Comment: Again?? "So the author of these notes made a mistake ?" I cannot say since you do not reproduce what the author wrote.